# Reduce Compile and Deployment Time in Android Studio when Debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, audio

My Android application contains a large amount of audio files bundled into a raw directory. As I'm debugging, it takes a minute and a half to two minutes to compile and deploy to my phone, even if I make a small layout change. I'm guessing that is because of the large audio files. Is there a way to reduce this time? I don't need to compile and deploy the audio files every time I make a small change. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried Instant Run?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small workaround that could be used to reduce the compilation time, however, it isn't always successful. If you navigate to the following directory:

```
/home/<username>/.gradle/ (Linux)
/Users/<username>/.gradle/ (Mac)
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle (Windows)
```

You can create a new file called `gradle.properties`. In that file, type:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Adding the above text will tell Gradle to use a daemon to build. Try to build your app. Does it improve the speed?